# Retained fragment does not work correctly when returning to application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a retained fragment that works fine when rotating the screen (after call to the parent application's onCreate()).

However as soon as I leave the application and return to it (for example by going to the home screen and then returning to my app), the fragment does not seem to behave correctly.

So essentially what is happening is that each time I 'return' to my Activity the fragment within seems to be 'reset' in some way. Is this something to do with fragment transactions potentially?

---

On the last call to Log.d() the gameFragment.testValue is returning null - how does this occur? The only place I set the value is through the earlier condition block. How would the fragment be created without that value being set?

```
        gameFragment = (GameFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("gameFragment");


    if (gameFragment == null)
    {
        gameFragment = new GameFragment();
        gameFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

        gameFragment.testValue = new Random().nextInt(1000);
        Log.d("hmm", " after set test value:" +gameFragment.testValue);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(gameFragment, "gameFragment").commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

        gameFragment.testValue = new Random().nextInt(1000);
        Log.d("hmm", " after commit, after set test value:" +gameFragment.testValue);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("hmm", "test value:" +gameFragment.testValue);
    }
```

Comment: Probably your fragment gets recreated behind the scenes after you leave the application using the default constructor. Try debugging through your app and setup breakpoint in your GameFragment constructor to confirm or put some debug info log inside the constructor to confirm.

EDIT: default constructor would be used when creating fragment thorough Fragment.instantate.

Comment: I would agree that it gets recreated. But how would this occur? I'll try debugging it now.

Comment: Your app might got destroyed.
Can you check if the fragment was actually retained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) you will find

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor.
>   The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed,
>   in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this
>   constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not
>   available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state
>   restore.

Consider setting up the parameters through `setArguments` method and bundle - this way, when Android recreates the Fragment it will be able to set the params to old values.

Something to support the thesis: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: So retained fragments only work for 'configuration changes'? This seems so unnecessarily limiting. Is there any alternative? I would like to maintain references to objects like SoundPool / MediaPlayer which aren't easily 'serializeable'.

Comment: I'm not sure what are your use cases, but keeping reference to SoundPool or MediaPlayer sounds more like you should have a look on using Service for it.

Comment: @Chris: "I would like to maintain references to objects like SoundPool / MediaPlayer which aren't easily 'serializeable'" -- that is not possible when your process is terminated. Instead, you need to hold onto the details to be able to recreate the `MediaPlayer` or `SoundPool` later on. "you should have a look on using Service for it" -- while using a `Service` for media playback may make sense, if it is supposed to play when the app is in the background, using a service just to try to keep your process around a bit longer is user-hostile and sloppy.

Comment: @CommonsWare "using a service just to try to keep your process around a bit longer is user-hostile and sloppy."  I agree on that, but since the use cases are unknown, it's one of the solutions.

Comment: @DamianWalczak: Had your comment put some caveats around the service option, I wouldn't have commented on it. [Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Continuous background playback is the primary use case of a service for a media player.

Comment: @CommonsWare good, that you noticed that, as my note wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

> On the last call to Log.d() the gameFragment.testValue is returning null - how does this occur?

One possibility would be that your process had been terminated. Android will recreate your fragments using the zero-argument public constructor, and it will give you your `savedInstanceState` `Bundle`. But the "retain" part of a "retained fragment" is only for configuration changes, so anything retained solely by that means will be lost.

Comment: @Chris: It's not related, strictly speaking. You will be called with `onSaveInstanceStated()`, in your activity and fragments, around the time the activity is going into the background (e.g., `onPause()`), in cases where Android is not going to immediately destroy the activity (e.g., HOME, not BACK). You can save state in the supplied `Bundle`. That `Bundle` is passed back to you *if* your process had been terminated *and* your app is still in the recent tasks list, *or* if your activity was destroyed and recreated due to a configuration change.

Comment: Apologies I deleted my comment before I saw your reply. I didn't know what the Bundle instance was referring to (which method).